# Dns network/interfaces, config broken

Tags: debian, networking

Today, while trying to set up an ip failover, I executed an order:

"ip addr flush dev ens3"

Result: my vps no longer responds, I am forced to go into rescue mode.

Before everything was planted, I was in "ens3" with more or less the same parameters. I am running under debian 9.

```
/etc/network/interfaces

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

---

```
> **"/sbin/route -n"**
> 
>  Kernel IP routing table  Destination     Gateway         Genmask 

> Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

>  0.0.0.0         193.70.**.*     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
>  193.70.**.*     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
```

---

```
> **> "root@rescue-pro:/# /sbin/ifconfig -a"**
> 
>  eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fa:16:3e:b9:**:**
>            inet addr:193.70.**.***  Bcast:193.70.**.***  Mask:255.255.255.255
> 
>            inet6 addr: ***::f816:3eff:feb9:****/64 Scope:Link
> 
>            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>            RX packets:18002 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>            TX packets:10814 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>            RX bytes:23202759 (22.1 MiB)  TX bytes:820631 (801.3 KiB)
> 
>  lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
>            inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>            inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
>            UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
>            RX packets:43 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>            TX packets:43 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>            collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
>            RX bytes:9320 (9.1 KiB)  TX bytes:9320 (9.1 KiB)
```

---

```
> **"root@rescue-pro:/# uname -a"** Linux rescue-pro 3.16.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.51-3+deb8u1 (2018-01-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

```
> **"root@rescue-pro:/# lspci | grep -i eth"** 00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Red Hat, Inc Virtio network device
```

---

Thank you for your help, I'm completely dropped!